# Parallel Assignment and Ranges

Tags: ruby, syntax

I think the answer is simply, "no you can't do that," but my thoughts are pretty much always wrong about Ruby.

I'm trying to do this in Ruby

```
city, state, zip = (0..2)
```

this results in city being a Range and the others being nil, which is not what I want. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With splat operator

```
city, state, zip = *(0..2)
```

With cast to array

```
city, state, zip = (0..2).to_a
```

Comment: So what is the difference between splat and to_a? At least in this case, the result is always an array.

Comment: There's no difference in this case. In practical terms, the splat operator essentially replaces an Enumerable with its constituent elements. So if you write `[*[1,2], *[3], 4]`, the result is `[1,2,3,4]`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes

```
city, state, zip = *(0..2)
```